# pivoting unique values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, duplicate

I have data with insurance policies and I want to pivot on the amount of policies sold per month.
A pivot table summarizes the count of the rows of the policies, even though there are duplicate ID values.
I don't want to use the 'erase duplicate rows' feature before pivoting, since it will also discard the price data which is in a different column.
The only solution I could think of is adding another column, put "1" in a row if the value has already appeared previously, and "0" otherwise, however I have no Idea how to implement such a thing.

for example- in the picture here, the pivot table count is 21 (the amount of rows in the data), but the number of unique values is 18, which is the number I am trying to get.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, create your pivot table and check the box for "Add this data to the data model".

[image]

Next, right click on a policy id cell on your pivot, and select "Value Field Settings". Within the Summarize Value Field By field, select "Distinct Count".

[image]

The pivot will now display the distinct number of policies:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have to add it to the data model?

Comment: @StianYttervik Yes, otherwise you cannot count distinct values.

Comment: That was odd. You are right of course, I had to try it myself. No distinct values without adding to the data model. I guess it is a function only available to data cubes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a formula for the helper column:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E$1:E2,E2)>1,0,1)
```

That should be input into `G2` (or row 2 of whatever column you use) and copied down.

Comment: The formula was exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much!! :)